# AutoKey trigger abbreviation with arguments

Tags: automation, scripting, autokey

I was wondering if there was a way to type
`;orf my-svc.yaml` into the terminal, and Autokey would automatically replace it with the actual command I wish to run:

```
oc delete -f my-svc.yaml && oc apply -f my-svc.yaml && watch -n 1 oc get po
```

That is, is sending arguments to abbreviations or triggers a thing in Autokey? If not, what can I do to make this task easier over the long term?

(The code is just an example, there are other commands that I have to run multiple times throughout the day and it is quite tedious)